# Android: change TimePickerDialog picker (circle) background color

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-timepicker

Is there any way of changing the background color marked bellow?
[image]

Until now I managed to change the background color like this:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog" >
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">#141414</item>
</style>
```

and applied it like this:

```
TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogTheme, listener, hour, minute, false);
```

I'm running Android Pie.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @RafaelaLourenço: No, and according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53306623/5284162, I believe this isn't supported either.

Answer (score -1):

by  change `numbersBackgroundColor` attribute

```
<style name="MyTimePickerWidgetStyle" 
 parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.TimePicker">
<item name="android:headerBackground">#ffe082</item>
<item name="android:numbersTextColor">#b71c1c</item>
<item name="android:numbersInnerTextColor">#f44336</item>
<item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">#33691e</item>
<item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">#ef9a9a</item>
<item name="android:amPmTextColor">#9c27b0</item>
```

Hope it works

Comment: Using your suggestion will result in a fullscreen dialog with the TimePicker aligned to the top of the screen but without any of the specified colors. I tried adding the numbersBackgroundColor attribute to my style but it does not change anything.